# Woocommerce: Prevent sending of email when order is "Completed"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, email

How can I prevent an email being sent when the order is marked as Completed?

Answer (score 1):

you can unhook the email action by placing this code in your functions.php:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

@Klevis Miho

> > add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );
> >
> > function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {
> >     remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
> >     }